# Как при установке приложения поместить его иконку на рабочий стол?

Tags: android

Пишу программу. Нужно чтобы при ее установке иконка появлялась на рабочем столе пользователя. Не могу найти как это сделать.

Comment: это невозможно. Максимум, что можно сделать - добавлять ярлык при **первом запуске**, как ниписал @nekaneka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если приложение устанавливается из google play, то иконку на главный экран добавляет само приложение google play, делать это в приложении не нужно.

Эта возможность может быть отключена в настройках google play, но и в этом случае добавлять иконку самостоятельно не стоит.

Answer (score 8):

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setClassName("packageName", "className");

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "shortcut_name");
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.icon));
addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

И разрешение в манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854197/how-can-i-place-app-icon-on-launcher-home-screen)