# При установке приложений через Android studio как сделать чтобы ярлык появился на рабочем столе телефона

Tags: java, android

Сначала добавил разрешение `INSTALL_SHORTCUT` в android manifest xml. Но не помогло `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />`.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_SHORTCUT

А вот сама студия просто загружает приложение на телефон, создание установочного apk и его последующая установка не происходит, потому что приложение находится в дебаг режиме и связано с самой студией.

Comment: Невозможно сделать да?

Comment: @gorilla, возможно, но только программно в уже запущенном приложении: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422372/11515. Для API26+ метод создания приведён в доке к `INSTALL_SHORTCUT`. При установке приложения из маркета ярлык создаёт сам маркет - в самом приложении ничего делать для этого не нужно.